# Hacer debugg dentro de una función utilizando Visual Studio Code con Python

Tags: python, vscode

Mi problema es que al usar el *debug* de Visual Studio Code con Python este se salta las funciones, cuando pongo mi *breakpoint* dentro de la función este se lo salta y pasa a la siguiente función, cuando lo que quiero es hacer *debug* al código dentro de la función.

Por ejemplo:

```
def funcion1():
    for i in range(0, 4):
        pass

def funcion2()
```

Supongamos que quiero hacer *debug* al bucle de la funcion1, pongo mi *breakpoint* en el bucle pero el *debugger* lo ignora y pasa directo a la siguiente función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba asi a ver si asi te aparece el breakpoint

```
 def funcion1():
for i in range(0, 4):
    print(i) #Haz que pinte algo en consola y colocalo aqui.
    pass

funcion1() # O llama a la funcion
```